# Gradient of transfer function (z-transform) with respect to coefficients/parameters?

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function, derivative, derivation

my problem is perhaps very simple but I just can not find the answer, even though this is used (though not explained) in several books:

What is $\frac{\partial G (z, \theta)}{\partial \theta}$ when $G$ is some transfer function, and $\theta$ the coefficients? (at least I call them coefficients). I tried using "regular" calculus on the following, but the result is very strange.

**Example**:
$$G(z, \theta) = \frac{b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2}}{1 + a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2} + a_3 z^{-3}} = \frac{B}{A}$$

$$ \theta = [b_1, b_2, a_1, a_2, a_3] $$
Using the chain rule, and treating this as a regular rational function in $z$, I get:
$$ \frac{\partial G (z, \theta)}{\partial \theta} = [\frac{\partial G (z, \theta)}{\partial b_1}, ..., \frac{\partial G (z, \theta)}{\partial a_3}] \\[19pt] 
= [\frac{z^{-1}}{A}, \frac{z^{-2}}{A}, (-1)z^{-1}\frac{ B}{A^2}, (-1)z^{-2}\frac{ B}{A^2 }, (-1)z^{-3}\frac{ B}{A^2}] \\[19pt] $$

*I agree, this looks weird.*

EDIT: What I am looking for is the gradient, $\nabla_\theta G$.

Perheps there are some rules of differentiation in this domain that I do not know.
The problem is related to parameter estimation.

Comment: Well, the question here is "what kind of derivative do you need?" We've got different ones to pick from: What you describe is closest to what's called *total derivative* and noted $\mathrm d G$, but it's possible you actually need the *gradient*, $\nabla_{\hspace{-0.25ex}\theta} G$. You say "related to parameter estimation", but that's not really clarifying what you're trying to do with that derivative.

Comment: Ok, thanks for feedback. The last comment was just for some context, since this might be unusual (?). It is indeed the gradient that I need, I will edit the post.

Comment: well, then what you're doing looks right!

Comment: This is right. Take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/59718/4298) where I've written down those derivatives.